# Possible logical flaw in a C++ test example

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

At my university, there is a practical programming test in C++ - and I'm stuck with an example where I am unsure about wheter or not the task in question is even valid and possible to complete correctly.

**The (simple) tasks:**

- Complete the destructor of `Person`, so that the allocated `name` is freed again
- In the main function, replace `//???` with the statement required to free the previously allocated memory

At first, the tasks seemed trivial for me: For the destructor, simply write `delete[] name` and in the main function, use `delete[] friends`. Presumably, that is also what the author of this example meant us to do.

**However:**

There seems to be a flaw in this code example, which causes memory leaks as well as destructors to be called more than once.

The person class has no assignment `operator =`, meaning that as the existing Person objects such as `maria` are assigned to slots in the `friends` array in the main function, the internal allocated `name`s are not copied. So two objects now share the same internal `char*` pointer! Moreover, the pointer to the name of the `Person` previously residing in the said array slot is permanentely lost, leading to an unavoidable memory leak.

As `delete[] friends;` is called - the objects in the array are destroyed - leading to their destructors being called and freeing their `name` members. When the program ends, though, the local Person objects in the scope of `main` are destructed - which of course have their `name` members still pointing to memory which was already freed before.

**The actual question:**

- Is this test example flawed, or am I missing something?
- Can the issues listed above be fixed if sticking fully to carrying out the given tasks (altering just the implementation of the destructor, and inserting new code at the commented part in the main function)?

..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int strlen(const char *str) {
    if (str==0) return 0;
    int i=0;
    for (; str[i]; ++i);
    return i;
}

void strcpy(const char *src, char *dest) {
    if (src==0 || dest==0) return;
    int i=0;
    for (; src[i]; ++i) dest[i]=src[i];
    dest[i]=’\0’;
}

class Person {
    char *name;
public:
    Person(const char *str = "Susi") {
        name = new char[strlen(str)+1];
        strcpy(str,name);
    }

    Person(const Person &p) {
        name = new char[strlen(p.name)+1];
        strcpy(p.name,name);
    }

    ~Person() {
        //...
    }

    void change() {
        name[4]='e';
    }

    ostream &print(ostream &o) const {
        o<<name;
        return o;
    }
};

int main() {
    Person maria("Maria"), peter("Peter"), franz("Franz"), luisa("Luisa");
    Person mary(maria);
    Person luise;
    Person p(luise);

    Person *friends= new Person[7];
    friends[0]=maria;
    friends[1]=peter;
    friends[2]=franz;
    friends[3]=luisa;
    friends[4]=mary;
    friends[5]=luise;
    friends[6]=p;
    friends[5]=luisa;
    friends[3].change();
    friends[4].change();

    for (int i=0; i<7; ++i) {
    friends[i].print(cout);
    cout<<endl;
    }

    //???
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are correct. The [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) is being violated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely right.  You *can* fix it by only making changes at the indicated positions, however they are going to be rather extreme:

Replace the `//...` inside the destructor with:

```
    delete[] name;
}

Person& operator=(const Person& other)
{
    if (this != &other) {
        delete[] name;  // not completely exception-safe!
        name = new char[strlen(other.name)+1];
        strcpy(other.name,name);
    }
    return *this;
```

**Another serious problem is redefining a standard function (`strcpy`) with a new definition that reorders the arguments.**

(See also: SQL injection attacks, which also cause existing pairs of syntax elements, frequently quotes and parentheses, to be re-paired with inserted syntax elements)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Your fix is also unsafe -- it simply swallows any sort of exception.  The correct exception-safe approach would be to use `std::vector` or `std::string` to hold the string data.

Comment: @BenVoight: Yup, I forgot the `throw;` at the end of the catch block. http://ideone.com/lZ0D2.  You're right that I would use a `std::string`, but that would require more substantial changes.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Right, and the existing constructors also aren't exception-safe.  More invasive changes would be needed, so I chose just to leave a comment noting the possibility.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the test example is flawed, possibly it was done consciously. Class `Person` definitely need assignment operator, remember the [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).
2. No, it's not possible. Default compiler-generated assignment operator will leak memory allocated by objects in `friends` array and double-delete memory allocated by auto `Person` objects.

Answer (score -1):

For every new there should be a delete[].

Comment: For each `new` a `delete`, and for each `new[]` a `delete[]`.